# Acessar métodos de outro Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Eu tenho um Form chamado `TelaInicio` onde tenho um método `CarregarGrid()` eu gostaria de acessar esse método através do meu outro Form `Cadastrar` eu já deixei o método `CarregarGrid()`como público mas ainda sim não tenho acesso a ele eu instanciei o form `TelaInicio` dessa forma

```
 public Cadastrar(TelaInicio telainicio)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.telainicio = telainicio;
    }
```

e na `TelaInicio` eu chamo ele em um botão

```
        private void Cadastrar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Cadastrar form = new Cadastrar(this);
        form.ShowDialog();
    }
```

e na `TelaInicio` meu método está como `public void CarregaGrid()`, mas ainda sim no outro form quando tento acessar ele diz que o método não existe

```
public void CarregarGrid()
    {
        try{
        //indico o número de colunas
        dgvDados.ColumnCount = 14;
        objConnection = new MySqlConnection(caminho);
        //instância do comando onde passo
        //o sql e a conexão como parâmetro
        objComando =  new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM checagens", objConnection);
        //abro a conexão
        objConnection.Open();
        //instâncio o leitor
        var leitor = objComando.ExecuteReader();
        //enquanto leitor está lendo
        while (leitor.Read())
        {
            //insiro os dados no dgvDados
            dgvDados.Rows.Add(leitor[0].ToString(),
                leitor[1].ToString(),
                leitor[2].ToString(),
                leitor[3].ToString(),
                leitor[4].ToString(),
                leitor[5].ToString(),
                leitor[6].ToString(),
                leitor[7].ToString(),
                leitor[8].ToString(),
                leitor[9].ToString(),
                leitor[10].ToString(),
                leitor[11].ToString(),
                leitor[12].ToString(),
                leitor[13].ToString());

        }
    }
        catch(Exception ex){
            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "" + ex, "Erro", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
        }
        finally{
        //fecho conexão
        objConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Estou chamando o método dentro do `button` Cadastrar no form `Cadastrar`

```
  if (cadchecagem(checagem))
        {

            MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Dados cadastrados com sucesso ", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
            Utilidades.Funcoes.LimparCampos(gbchecagem);
            CarregarGrid();

        }
    }
```

Ele apresenta o erro:

> The name 'CarregarGrid' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Onde está o método "CarregarGrid"? De preferência coloque as 2 classes na sua pergunta para facilitar a análise

Comment: eu editei a pergunta e adicionei o método mas acredito que nao vai surtir diferença vc ver ele

Comment: Não localizei onde você está tentando acessar o método de um form através de outro, você precisa incluir o trecho de código onde está apresentando o erro.

Comment: Pode coloca-lo como estático ou melhor criar um manager para acessar toda a classe.

Comment: Olá Patrick. Coloque a parte do código onde você chama o método `CarregarGrid()` a partir do `Cadastrar`.

Comment: @CypherPotato Editado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método realmente não existe no contexto onde está sendo chamado, pois ele está sendo chamado como se fosse membro de `Cadastrar`. Não foi especificado onde está esse método nem da onde irá chamá-lo.

Você deve especificar quem irá chamar o método. Fez certo em tornar ele público na classe `TelaInicio` e instanciar ele por parâmetro em seu construtor, agora para chamar este método, considere:

```
if (cadchecagem(checagem))
    {

        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Dados cadastrados com sucesso ", "Sucesso", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk);
        Utilidades.Funcoes.LimparCampos(gbchecagem);

        // Aqui ele estará procurando onde está este método, no seu caso, está no telainicio
        this.telainicio.CarregarGrid();
    }
}
```

E lembre-se, `telainicio` deve estar declarado dentro do `Cadastrar` como membro de classe e não de método:

```
// declarado e setado no ctor da classe
internal TelaInicio telainicio = null;

public Cadastrar(TelaInicio telainicio)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.telainicio = telainicio;
}
```

Comment: nao sabia que a forma correta de chamar o método era esse muito obrigado, adicionei também o `internal TelaInicio telainicio = null;` porém na hora de executar o programa ele da um erro dizendo **Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class** apresenta esse erro na classe `TelaInicio`

Comment: Adicionei também a classe `TelaInicio` na pergunta, não tem nada de diferente nela não sei se devo adicionar algo a classe

Comment: consegui arrumar, valeuuu